# const pointer as class field assign

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm back to C++ and little help is needed. I know what's const pointer, but I can find out, how to assign it in constructor properly That's frustrating ;)

so for example:

```
public:
  TransferManager::TransferManager( Account * source, double amount )
  { 
    account = source; // that doesn't work ;)
  }

private:
  Account * const account;
```

`1>proj1.cpp(63): error C2166: l-value specifies const object`

That error msg isn't clear for me.

I did some research, but all I did find was difference bettwen const pointer, pointer to const var, and const pointer to const var...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the initializer-list to initialize const members:

```
TransferManager::TransferManager( Account * source, double amount ) : account(source) {
}
```

The error message is saying that you're trying to assign to something that is const - that's not permitted. You have to *initialize* such member variables, not assign to them.

Comment: It's "initializ/ation/ list", an initializ/er/ list is a new construct from C++0x to enable `std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }`.

Comment: @filmor: Actually it's `mem-initializer-list` in the c++03 standard.

Comment: So also here C++ `const` is different from Java `final`... ;) Thanks a lot!

Comment: @dantuch: Yes, `final` and `const` have some resemblances, but they are in no way the same.